# Azure Function - Powershell - Graph SDK - Get users/Groups

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to get some users information via Azure function using graph SDK.
While I'm able to connect and print out the context every time I try to use users or groups cmdlets I get ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Can anyone help with this?

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)


$appid = 'eaf7a235'
$tenantid = '723058'
$secret = '~SomeCode'
 
$body =  @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    Client_Id     = $appid
    Client_Secret = $secret
}
 
$connection = Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token `
    -Method POST `
    -Body $body
 
$token = $connection.access_token  | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
 

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token

$user = Get-MgUser -UserId 'someone@here.com' | convertto-json -depth 100 ##here the function crash


Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $user
})
```

I've tried the same with get group commandlet.
Tried same code in a powershell window and it work.

Comment: No, this is not production code.  I've included it in the post so people can authenticate faster without a vault of other configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to serialize a `MicrosoftGraphUser`, it will create an infinite loop and your function will run out of memory:

[image: graph is a piece of shit]

Use [`Invoke-MgGraphRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.authentication/invoke-mggraphrequest?view=graph-powershell-1.0) instead with [`-OutputType Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.authentication/invoke-mggraphrequest?view=graph-powershell-1.0#-outputtype):

```bash
$user = Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET 'v1.0/users/someone@here.com' -OutputType Json
```

Or reduce the serialization `-Depth`.

---

As aside, please don't hardcode your secret in your function's body, use a Key Vault instead. Furthermore, you can use your function's [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) if you have it enabled:

```bash
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken (ConvertTo-SecureString $token.Token -AsPlainText)
```

**NOTE:** Add `Az.Accounts` in your `requirements.psd1` or place the module in the function's [`Modules` folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#folder-structure) for `Connect-AzAccount`.

Comment: Thank you Santiago, Invoke-MgGraphRequest works. Get-MgUser still returns the error even with dept 4. "Result: ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." does it work for you ? 

Please note that I've included this type of connection in this post to help people with testing faster, this is not used in prod.

Comment: @user23371259 with depth 3 or 4 for example it serializes just fine for me but I do get that warning from screenshot. Perhaps you have an older module version

Comment: mhh I'm on 2.12.0, I'll try to update and re-try, thank you!

Comment: fast update, I'm getting a JSON object back but all the proprieties are null :/ , all working if I use the Invoke-MgGraphRequest

Comment: @user23371259 using `Get-MgUser` or `Invoke-MgGraphRequest` ? if you're still using `Get-MgUser` this is expected. That object is a backbone of a Graph User but there are many properties that can be only returned on `$select` (`-Select`). You need to check the Graph API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0. The beta endpoint will return more properties by default.